# How to loop cut a hexagon into 8 parts

Tags: loop

I'd like to cut a hexagonal cylinder into 8 parts. I don't understand why the cut isn't going all around it, but instead it is just on one face. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Example]

Comment: If you use Ctrl R to create an edge loop, it can only cut a quad, it can't cut a ngon, because it doesn't know where it is supposed to cut. What you can do, depending on how you want to cut the top face, is either use a knife (K to activate), or inset the top face with "i", or J to join 2 vertices, etc

Comment: Hello. Above the ngon issue, what are the 8 parts you want to obtain?